# C# dll injection not loading dll

Tags: c#, c, .net, dll, dll-injection

I know there are a few similar questions here on stackoverflow, but none of them solved my problem.

So I am writing a c# framework for low level inter process operations including a dll injection feature.

Before calling my injector I am already attached to the target process (in this case notepad++.exe) using `OpenProcess()` with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` permissions.
The following is my injector code (I know readability suffered quite a lot due to all the debug prints):

```
public void Inject(string dllName, bool printDebugInfo)
{
    // Check if we are attached to the process.
    target.Assertions.AssertProcessAttached();
    target.Assertions.AssertInjectionPermissions();

    // searching for the address of LoadLibraryA and storing it in a pointer
    IntPtr kernel32Handle = WinAPI.GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
    if (kernel32Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        uint errorCode = WinAPI.GetLastError();
        throw new Win32Exception((int)errorCode, "Encountered error " + errorCode.ToString() + " (0x" + errorCode.ToString("x") + ") - FATAL: Could not get handle of kernel32.dll: was NULL.");
    }
    UIntPtr loadLibraryAddr = WinAPI.GetProcAddress(kernel32Handle, "LoadLibraryA");
    if (loadLibraryAddr == UIntPtr.Zero)
    {
        uint errorCode = WinAPI.GetLastError();
        throw new Win32Exception((int)errorCode, "Encountered error " + errorCode.ToString() + " (0x" + errorCode.ToString("x") + ") - FATAL: Could not get address of LoadLibraryA: was NULL.");
    }
    HelperMethods.Debug("LoadLibraryA is at 0x" + loadLibraryAddr.ToUInt64().ToString("x"), printDebugInfo);

    // alocating some memory on the target process - enough to store the name of the dll
    // and storing its address in a pointer
    uint size = (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char)));
    IntPtr allocMemAddress = WinAPI.VirtualAllocEx(target.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, size, (uint)Permissions.MemoryPermission.MEM_COMMIT | (uint)Permissions.MemoryPermission.MEM_RESERVE, (uint)Permissions.MemoryPermission.PAGE_READWRITE);
    HelperMethods.Debug("Allocated memory at 0x" + allocMemAddress.ToInt64().ToString("x"), printDebugInfo);

    int bytesWritten = 0;
    // writing the name of the dll there
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dllName);
    Array.Copy(bytes, 0, buffer, 0, bytes.Length);
    buffer[buffer.Length - 1] = 0;
    bool success = WinAPI.WriteProcessMemory((uint)target.Handle, allocMemAddress.ToInt64(), buffer, size, ref bytesWritten);
    if (success)
    {
        HelperMethods.Debug("Successfully wrote \"" + dllName + "\" to 0x" + allocMemAddress.ToInt64().ToString("x"), printDebugInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        HelperMethods.Debug("FAILED to write dll name!", printDebugInfo);
    }
    // creating a thread that will call LoadLibraryA with allocMemAddress as argument
    HelperMethods.Debug("Injecting dll ...", printDebugInfo);
    IntPtr threadHandle = WinAPI.CreateRemoteThread(target.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadLibraryAddr, allocMemAddress, 0, out IntPtr threadId);
    HelperMethods.Debug("CreateRemoteThread returned the following handle: 0x" + threadHandle.ToInt32().ToString("x"), printDebugInfo);
    uint errCode = WinAPI.GetLastError();
    if (threadHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception((int)errCode, "Encountered error " + errCode.ToString() + " (0x" + errCode.ToString("x") + ") - FATAL: CreateRemoteThread returned NULL pointer as handle.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("CreateRemoteThread threw errorCode 0x" + errCode.ToString("x"));
    Console.WriteLine("Currently the following modules are LOADED:");
    ProcessModuleCollection processModules = target.Process.Modules;
    foreach (ProcessModule module in processModules)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  - " + module.FileName);
    }
    uint waitExitCode = WinAPI.WaitForSingleObject(threadHandle, 10 * 1000);
    HelperMethods.Debug("Waiting for thread to exit ...", printDebugInfo);
    HelperMethods.Debug("WaitForSingleObject returned 0x" + waitExitCode.ToString("x"), printDebugInfo);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Currently the following modules are LOADED:");
    processModules = target.Process.Modules;
    foreach (ProcessModule module in processModules)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  - " + module.FileName);
    }
    success = WinAPI.GetExitCodeThread(threadHandle, out uint exitCode);
    if (!success)
    {
        uint errorCode = WinAPI.GetLastError();
        throw new Win32Exception((int)errorCode, "Encountered error " + errorCode.ToString() + " (0x" + errorCode.ToString("x") + ") - FATAL: Non-zero exit code of GetExitCodeThread.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Currently the following modules are LOADED:");
    processModules = target.Process.Modules;
    foreach (ProcessModule module in processModules)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  - " + module.FileName);
    }
    HelperMethods.Debug("Remote thread returned 0x" + exitCode.ToString("x"), printDebugInfo);
    success = WinAPI.CloseHandle(threadHandle);
    if (!success)
    {
        uint errorCode = WinAPI.GetLastError();
        throw new Win32Exception((int)errorCode, "Encountered error " + errorCode.ToString() + " (0x" + errorCode.ToString("x") + ") - FATAL: Failed calling CloseHandle on 0x" + threadHandle.ToInt64().ToString("x") + ".");
    }
    HelperMethods.Debug("Called CloseHandle on 0x" + threadHandle.ToInt64().ToString("x") + ".", printDebugInfo);
    success = WinAPI.VirtualFreeEx(target.Handle, allocMemAddress, 0, 0x8000);
    if (!success)
    {
        uint errorCode = WinAPI.GetLastError();
        throw new Win32Exception((int)errorCode, "Encountered error " + errorCode.ToString() + " (0x" + errorCode.ToString("x") + ") - FATAL: Failed calling VirtualFreeEx on 0x" + allocMemAddress.ToInt64().ToString("x") + ".");
    }
    HelperMethods.Debug("Released all previously allocated resources!", printDebugInfo);
}
```

All the WinAPI functions being called as specified by official Microsoft documentation (triple-checked that).

I am calling my code as follows

```
Target target = Target.CreateFromName("notepad++");
target.Attach(Permissions.ProcessPermission.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS);
target.Injector.Inject(@"L:\Programming\C\test\newdll.dll",true);
```

The full source code of the `Target` class is on [GitHub](https://github.com/frederik-hoeft/InteropManager) but shouldn't be relevant for this question.

probably the most interesting here being the `newdll.dll` that is written in native C as follows:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
__declspec(dllexport) bool WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code obviously doesn't do much, but as spawning something like a messagebox from the DllMain is apparently considered "bad" I left it like this. However if the injection was working the dll would be listed in `Process.Modules` (which it isn't).

However when running my code I get the following output from all the debug prints:

```
LoadLibraryA is at 0x778f60b0
Allocated memory at 0x9c0000
Successfully wrote "L:\Programming\C\test\newdll.dll" to 0x9c0000
Injecting dll ...
CreateRemoteThread returned the following handle: 0x22c
CreateRemoteThread threw errorCode 0x0
Currently the following modules are LOADED:
  - J:\TOOLS\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
Waiting for thread to exit ...
WaitForSingleObject returned 0x0
Currently the following modules are LOADED:
  - J:\TOOLS\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
Currently the following modules are LOADED:
  - J:\TOOLS\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
  - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
Remote thread returned 0x0
Called CloseHandle on 0x22c.
Released all previously allocated resources!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As can be seen there are no error codes or any indications really that the injection went wrong, except that the `newdll.dll` was never loaded, as it doesn't show up in the loaded modules in `Process.Modules`.

**So what's wrong with my code?**

Quick overview: I do follow the procedure of:

- `OpenProcess()` with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`
- `GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll")`
- `GetProcAddress(kernel32Handle, "LoadLibraryA")`
- `VirtualAllocEx(...)` and `WriteProcessMemory()` to write my dll name and path.
- `CreateRemoteThread()` to load the dll
- `WaitForSingleObject()` to wait for the dll to be loaded
- Free all the resources previously allocated

Comment: Your injector app needs to have the same bit-ness as the target app for the LoadLibrary address to match. The dll's bit-ness needs to match too, of course.

Comment: Thank you. You solved 2 weeks of debugging just like that. That was exactly what the problem was. I was compiling as 64 bit and the target process was 32 bit :|

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was correctly pointed out this injection technique only works when injecting from 32 bit process --> 32 bit process or from 64 bit process --> 64 bit process. I was compiling my code as 64 bit executable, trying to inject my dll into the 32 bit notepad++.exe.

Also I had to adapt the `WriteProcessMemory` call to comply with 32 bit memory space. So changing from `bool success = WinAPI.WriteProcessMemory((uint)target.Handle, allocMemAddress.ToInt64(), buffer, size, ref bytesWritten);` to `bool success = WinAPI.WriteProcessMemory((uint)target.Handle, allocMemAddress.ToInt32(), buffer, size, ref bytesWritten);` did the trick.